# Switch displays when one turned off (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 7 dual monitor setup. I want to trigger and event when I turn off one of the displays. More specifically, when I switch to projector only and the projector is powered off, I want to detect this and re-enable the primary monitor.

I have a scripting tool that can handle re-enabling part, bu I currently have no way of detecting when the projector is turned off

Any suggestions?  Is this even possible?

Comment: In Samsung notebook I have a program Easy Display Manager and it allows to handle such situations (after recognizing changes, e.g. plugging additional monitor, "EDM mini UI" is shown). I don't know if it will help in your situation, but you can try. I belive it's free and can be download.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds over-complicated.  Why use a script?  If you set the projector as a second monitor (like you might with a TV) and make it primary, Windows will handle switching back to the regular monitor when the projector is turned off.